# Can I pour epoxy pebble flooring over electric warm floor?

Tags: flooring

Can I pour epoxy pebble flooring over electric warm floor?  In our bathroom/laundry area, we plan to first lay hardiboard.  Then I may need floor leveler as well.  Should the warm floor be put down before the leveler (if I use leveler) and then can the epoxy flooring be put on top of all of it?

Answer (score 2):

You should first palce the hardiboard and leveler as needed then palce the heating elemetns. So the answer is going to be yes.

[image]

Is the expoxy going to be clear? If so it will shine through the emelents and cause some undesired effects. If that is the case then i suggest using tile adhesive to cover the heating elements and level it then place your pebbles masterpiece on top of that. Pebbles inheritly will take longer to heat up but they also take longer to cool down so that can be a plus for energy saving in winter.